# Keep chaperone walls always visible while in SteamVR?

Tags: steam-vr

Beacuse I have a limited playspace, and I can not help but having a few obstacles in the playspace near the edges, I would like to force chaperone to be always visible.

In this particular instance I'm playing BeatSaber. I want to keep track of where the edges of my playspace are, so I have less chance to break my hand/controller/door or all three. 
But this question isn't specific for Beat Saber, I would like to have chaperone always on, in any steamvr game or app. In some apps, like media players, the chaperone walls are not even visible at all. That's very annoying because now I have no reference to that other world anymore.

I have noticed the setting 'floor bounds always on' under 'chaperone settings', and I would expect an option there that says 'walls always on', but I coulnd't find such a thing.

Is there perhaps a secret setting in a config file somewhere? Or maybe even a hack that someone created?

Comment: It's been awhile since I played in a limited space, but I could swear there's an actual option for this in the settings for the Chaperone.  It was in with the settings that let you adjust how far apart the grid lines are.

Comment: @CDove perhaps you're thinking of the "floor bounds always on" option, which is located right there. But I don't see any such option for the walls.

Comment: I think that is the option for the walls.   One's feet tend to establish the floor boundary.  You don't really need to know how high or low you can travel on the Z axis.

Comment: @CDove when I turn it on, only the floor bounds stay visible. The walls still disapear when I move a little bit away. And in media apps, the walls are still not visible at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [OpenVR Advanced Settings](https://github.com/matzman666/OpenVR-AdvancedSettings) plug-in to force Chaperone boundaries to be visible at all times.

1. Once installed a new Advanced Settings menu will appear in SteamVR's dashboard
2. Go to the [Chaperone page](https://github.com/matzman666/OpenVR-AdvancedSettings#--chaperone-page) and turn on **Force Bounds**

There are also additional settings that may help you, such as marking the center of your playspace or proximity warnings when you are close to the boundary.